# laravel controller implicit user by auth vs explicit user route parameter

Tags: laravel, rest

I read a lot that routes/controllers should not rely on an implicit user:
E.g. to get the current users data I should do:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@index');
```

instead of:

```
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@self');
```

Do you strictly follow this approach? The second one seems more straight forward to me, since I do not need to know my own id and using the first case I might expose data from another user if I do not check for $user === auth()->user()

Comment: Why wouldn't you expose data in the first case if you don't check for authenticated user?

Comment: Search about roles and permission to secure your data from other user